# Control the cache of website App by html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I am developing a website.
My co-workers developed an App to read the site.

But the problem is the App has cache that will remember the front-end page.

Unless the user clear the cache of app,otherwise no matter how I modify the page, the page style and element won't change.
May I control the cache by using javascript or html?

I tried these:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/files/style.css?v=1.02">
```

both of them don't work.

Comment: Thats your coworkers job. Unless we know how the caching is implemented, its impossible to say how to refresh it.

Comment: I know that there must be a much better solution but this should work until somebody more experienced write it.
https://pastebin.com/it84DR3m

Comment: You increase `v=1.02` every time you change something and it does not help?

Comment: @Dmitry no it's not